# Xaml invalid markup error when trying to add sub menu items in MenuFlyoutSubItem

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Below is my xaml for a button where I am adding menu items. I am developing a Universal windows app (VS2015).

```
 <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Connections" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom" x:Name="ConnectionsMenu">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemOne" Text="Get Item One"></MenuFlyoutItem>

                        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Name="ItemTwo" Text="Get Item Two">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemTwoChildOne" Text="Item Two Child One"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemTwoChildTwo" Text="Item Two Child Two"/>
                        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
```

I am getting the invalid markup screen as shown below when I add menuflyoutitems to the menyflyoutsubitem tag as shown below. I am not sure why this happens.

[image]

This is the error in VS2015 **Error: Cannot add content to an object of type "MenuFlyoutSubItem".**

But the application run fines when I build and run as shown below.

[image]

**I could not find resolution online for this, can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to go about this or am I missing something.**

**Update:**
this [link](http://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcmva/forum/tcmvacoursefdbk-tcmvawinappdev/cannot-add-content-to-an-object-of-type/2be5fc5c-66cb-4189-98b4-d9fbb58bce02) suggests to  modify VS to remove the installed features from Visual Studio. I installed all the features that comes with VS2015 especially for mobile and uwp app related and I cannot modify and re-install the features as it may cause other Visual studio problems. Is there a work around for this or try a different approach. Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to explicitly declare the MenuFlyoutSubItem Items type, as below

```
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Connections" Margin="5,0,10,0">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom" x:Name="ConnectionsMenu">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemOne" Text="Get Item One" />
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem Name="ItemTwo" Text="Get Item Two">
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem.Items>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemTwoChildOne" Text="Item Two Child One"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="ItemTwoChildTwo" Text="Item Two Child Two"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem.Items>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is for when you try to add content in xaml to a control that isn't a ContentControl. It still works because for a MenuFlyoutSubItem, it just treats those items as its "Items" property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutsubitem.items.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by turning off Option Explicit. I also had to implement the fix above using the ".Items" property.

Open your Visual Studio. Click on the "Tools" tab at the top. Go down the list and click on "Options..." After that, select "Projects and Solutions" and "VB Defaults". There are 4 options listed, at least in VS2015 Community Version. They are "Option Explicit", "Option Strict", "Option Compare", and "Option Infer". Select "Option Explicit" and make sure the drop down is displaying "Off".

After that, insert "MenuFlyoutSubItem.Items" tags into your code following the `<MenuFlyoutSubItem>` tags. After you've entered the menu sub-items, close with a MenuFlyoutSubItem.Items tag.